# Open source software which allows user to draw ER/flow diagrams for my web application

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, gwt

we are developing a web application which allows a user to draw diagrams(flow/ER diagrams) and we need the representation of that diagram in some XML or other formats. How should we acheive this ?? is there any open source software or jQuery plugin or anyother server side software??

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285828/open-source-er-diagramming-tool-for-mysql among many others

Comment: But all the other questions are related tools which help the users to draw E/R,Flow digrams our question is about software which allows us to easily use it in our web application

Answer (score 0):

How about something like [SlickMap](http://astuteo.com/slickmap/)? It lets you create the diagram structure as HTML, which then gets styled using CSS.