# Auto Generate Database Diagram for PHPMyadmin DB?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, diagram

i want tool for to generate DB diagram below, i need to generate particular db tables structure like below,

[image]

how can i do that?...is there any free tool or application is available for that. i already tried navicat8lite_ora_en and HeidiSQL. but i can't make it work.

Comment: and also a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285828/open-source-er-diagramming-tool-for-mysql which is a better choice.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) will reverse engineer and engineer scripts for you.  Output will be similar to what you have above, but not identical.

Comment: actually i tried above one. but i could not connect. i don't know whats the problem.

Comment: What error did you receive?  The MySQL Workbench will need to link to an active database to read from (if not using the SQL definition) and therefore, you would need the connection information (user name, password, etc...).

Answer (score 48):

Yes you can generate ERD with PHPMyAdmin. PHPMyadmin added this functionality from version 3.4

detail step to generate ERD: http://sforsuresh.in/generating-erd-using-phpmyadmin/

You can refer to PHPMyAdmin documentation for more info: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#pmadb

Comment: I don't know , why this post is not marked as answer while i gives the 100% precise answer . Great job

Comment: @ImranNaqvi My guess is that the OP accepted an answer long before this was posted. Also, a reader would prefer detailed answer instead of links only answer just in case the referenced webpages go down in future..

Comment: There's a problem when you have too many tables, it gets overlapping. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Vertabelo](http://www.vertabelo.com/). It's an online database modeler working under Chrome. It is:

- free to use,
- OS independent,
- allows versioning,
- supports model validation,
- generates SQL scripts for particular database:
- allows sharing your DB model with other members of your team,
- [allows reverse engineering](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/reverse-engineering) - so you can easily migrate your database to [Vertabelo](http://www.vertabelo.com/),
- suports following databases:

  - PostgreSQL,
  - MySQL,
  - Oracle,
  - IBM DB2,
  - HSQLDB,
  - MS SQL Server.

Comment: Vertabelo is not free, only for academic purpose it is free.